# bootstrap poner el texto alineado a dos puntos

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy usando la rejilla de boostrap para hacer una especie de tabla por llamarlo de alguna manera,
el problema que tengo es que la información que va dentro de las filas lleva dos puntos y necesito que el texto que va antes de los dos puntos tiene que estar alineado con ellos ejemplo

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  Nombre:Paco
</div>
<div class="col">
  Nombre persona:Paco
</div>
<div class="col">
  Nombre persona persona:Paco
</div>
```

en el ejemplo que he puesto es orientativo  para que te hagas una idea del problema, ahora el problema es que los textos se tienen que alinear para que los dos puntos casen con las múltiples líneas teniendo en cuenta las líneas son diferentes.
Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No estoy seguro si te refieres a esto: https://jsfiddle.net/wyoL6dnq/   (con bootstrap 5)

Comment: Pues si oye pues muchas gracias la verdad es que estoy un poco perdido con boostrap

Comment: me has salvado ahora solo tengo que adaptarlo para que cada fila tenga 3 columnas, gracias !!

Comment: Usa esa web (jsfiddle.net) para practicar sin miedo (pon siempre la primera linea como yo la he puesto para que invoque a bootstrap).  Bootstrap no es dificil, pero require practicar bastante para comprender bien su grid.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a algo asi con lo de las tres columnas: https://jsfiddle.net/wyoL6dnq/1/

Comment: si es algo asi solo que en lugar de que todas las columnas tengan el mismo texto que tengan texto diferente pero con lo que me has pasado, es de gran ayuda, ahora tengo que ver si la versión de boostrap que estoy usando el la 5 o no

Comment: La unica diferencia en ese codigo entre las versiones de bootstrap es usar `text-end` en bootstrap 5 o bien `text-right` en bootstrap 4... el resto funcionará igual